# If a finite group has all $p$-complements, is it always solvable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

On reading the question [Subgroups of Prime Power Index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661769/subgroups-of-prime-power-index) I immediately thought "if the group had a $p$-complement for each prime $p$ then it would be solvable".

But then I realized that the argument I had half-structured in my head was not actually correct, and I was not able to salvage it.
My basic idea was that it seems like one could apply Hall's criterion for solvability by taking suitable intersections of $p$-complements to get the desired Hall-subgroups. But on further consideration, it is not so clear why this should work.

Another idea was to do the same while looking at a minimal counterexample, but it was not clear to me why those $p$-complements should themselves satisfy the conditions (and hence, the minimality was not much use).

Comment: I find a system of Sylow complements to be the easiest version of a Hall system to work with. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392172/sylow-basis-of-finite-solvable-groups/392806#392806 includes a proof that your idea does work.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks. I see that the proof there mentions the same lemma that Andreas used in his answer, but I don't quite see the relation between them apart from that (seeing as that proof assumed the group to be solvable in the first place).

Comment: You can ignore the solvability hypothesis: it used to solely to conclude the existence of a Sylow complement basis. The proof is that every Sylow complement basis gives rise to a unique Hall system. Where-as knowing that you have some Hall subgroups does not give you immediate control, having a permutable system does, and this follows automatically from Sylow complements. I also link Hall's paper where he explains these ideas. In other words, you are asking about a theorem of Hall, and that answer includes proofs that simplify understanding Hall's ideas.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Ahh, I see. That is very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your idea is correct, it should be a matter of using the lemma that says that if the indices of the subgroups $A, B$ of $G$ are coprime, then
$$
\lvert G : A \cap B \rvert = \lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert G :  B \rvert.
$$

---

Let us prove the lemma, let us say in the case $G$ is finite, but you only need the two indices to be finite.

We have that $\lvert G : A \rvert$ divides $\lvert G : A \cap B \rvert = \lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert A : A \cap B \rvert$, and the same for $\lvert G : B \rvert$. Since the two indices are coprime, we have that their product $\lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert G :  B \rvert$ divides $\lvert G : A \cap B \rvert$.

But we also have 
$$
\lvert G : A \cap B \rvert = \lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert A : A \cap B \rvert = \lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert A B : B \rvert \le \lvert G : A \rvert \cdot \lvert G : B \rvert.
$$
Here I have used the fact that $\lvert A B : B \rvert = \lvert A : A \cap B \rvert$, that is, under *no* normality assumption, there is a bijection between the cosets of $B$ contained in  $AB = \{ab :a \in A, b \in B\}$ and the cosets of $A \cap B$ in $A$. The correspondence is given by $a B \mapsto a (A \cap B)$.

This is basically as in Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I, I.2.12 and I.2.13 (1967 Ed.).

Comment: That would certainly finish the proof using a minimal counterexample. But how does one prove this lemma then (it might be obvious and I am just overlooking something)?

Comment: I am adding a proof.

Comment: Finished adding proof.

Comment: Thank you, this is very neat. I was not familiar with that bijection.

Comment: It is very useful, and probably less known than the second isomorphism theorem, which holds when $B$ is normal in $A$.

Comment: Indeed (I guess you mean when $A$ normalizes $B$, ie when $B$ is normal in $AB$).

Comment: Absolutely, sorry.

Comment: BTW, would you like to add a few words on the complete proof then (to have the answer actually be to the question rather to the part I was missing in being able to answer it myself), or should I do that?

Comment: It's ok with me if you do it, it was your idea, thanks for asking.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer with the full proof (in probably more detail than really makes sense in a proof invoking Hall's criterion).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full proof using the lemma provided by Andreas Caranti in his answer.

Assume that $G$ is a non-solvable finite group which has a $p$-complement for any prime $p$ and assume that $G$ is minimal with this property.

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes and let $P$ and $Q$ be a $p$- and a $q$-complement in $G$ respectively. By the lemma, $P$ has a $q$-complement (namely $P\cap Q$), and since this was for arbitary $p$ and $q$, this shows that any $p$-complement in $G$ itself has $q$-complements for all primes $q$, and hence that these are all solvable by minimality of $G$.

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes. We wish to show that $G$ has a $\pi$-Hall subgroup.
Let $p$ be a prime not in $\pi$ but which divides $|G|$ (we can assume such a prime exists or a $\pi$-Hall subgroup would just be $G$). Now $G$ has a $p$-complement $P$, whose order is divisible by all primes in $\pi$, and since it is solvable, it has a $\pi$-Hall subgroup, which is thus a $\pi$-Hall subgroup of $G$.
Now $G$ is solvable by Hall's criterion (having $\pi$-Hall subgroups for all sets of primes $\pi$).